# How to insert seven kind of ids in a column to all values

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have column data. I need to insert ids in another column. Total i have 7 ids. For first 7 values i have to insert these ids and next 7 values, i have to insert same ids and so on.. Can any one please help?

```
Pay_headID   Pay_amount
16414         8000
16415          300
16416            0
16417          200
16418          500
16419            0
16420            0
16414         9000
16415          300
so on ...
```

Comment: what do you mean by "For first 7 values i have to insert these ids and next 7 values" ? what is the expected result ?

Comment: First 7 values are fields in the pay_amount column. i have more rows in the pay_amount column. and i have 7 ids. these 7 ids i have to maintain against pay_amount column. First 7 rows , 7 ids and next 7 rows same ids will be repeated and next 7 rows same ids will be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use CTE and ROW_NUMBER, i have used ordering by Pay_headId:

```
WITH cte_myTable
AS (SELECT
  *,
  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Pay_headID)) - 1 AS num
FROM myTable)
UPDATE cte_myTable
SET [Pay_headID] =
                  CASE
                    WHEN num % 7 = 0 THEN 16414
                    WHEN num % 7 = 1 THEN 16415
                    WHEN num % 7 = 2 THEN 16416
                    WHEN num % 7 = 3 THEN 16417
                    WHEN num % 7 = 4 THEN 16418
                    WHEN num % 7 = 5 THEN 16419
                    WHEN num % 7 = 6 THEN 16420
                  END
GO
```

If you want use ordering on how it was inserted, you can set Pay_headIds to null:

```
update myTable set Pay_headID=null;
```

Comment: I have 206192 values in a column. I need to maintain id in a separate column. i have total 7 Ids. For first 7 values need to maintain these ids, next 7 values need to maintain same ids and next 7 values need to maintain same 7 ids. Over all for 206192 i need to maintain same ids repeatedly in order.

Comment: in this case which ordering you want to use for understanding which recordrs are in the first group and which records should be in the second group?

Comment: records are in order only. for first 7 values need to give 7 ids, next 7 values need to give same ids.

Comment: ok, as I understood you have a lot of records with Pay_amount values in your table, Pay_headIDs for all of them are null. I have updated my answer, please try it and all your records will have ids from 16414 to 16420.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RowNum() to give you an artificial incrementing number, divide it by 7 and then Round it.

```
SELECT FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Pay_HeadID DESC))/7) AS MyID
```

to get your ids

Comment: Hi, Can you please explain it? Thanks

Comment: ROW_NUMBER gives you a counter for each record.  Then when you divide it by 7 and use FLOOR it only gives a new number every 7 records.  Which is what I thought you wanted. I don't know whether you want to insert these back in the table, or what, I'll leave that to you